# As good as I'd played

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Please tell me what's meant by the emboldened part

The best innings you ever played?
The Lord's Test in 1972, just because of the conditions and the situation of the game [Chappell scored 131 out of 308 to give Australia a narrow first-innings lead]. Technically and mentally it **was as good as I'd played**. The conditions were very much in favour of the bowlers.

Does it mean that was the best innings he ever played?

Comment: Yes, but not *exactly*. It means *[**as good as**] the best innings he **had** ever played* (the word ***ever*** is implicit in the cited text). That's to say, he may have played ***as well*** in the past, but never ***better***. (There's a strong implication that he *did* play that well in the past, but this isn't an absolute.)

Comment: Or could it mean that he thought that he did an excellent job of batting that day given that the conditions weren't ideal from the batter's point of view?

Comment: You can draw all sorts of implications that aren't explicitly *stated*. Quite possibly the speaker (Chappell?) knows perfectly that by *other people's* standards, his performance in 1972 wasn't considered anywhere near his best. He might have chosen to name it as "the best innings" purely because ***technically and mentally*** it stood out for him, even though he may have scored far more on many other occasions. But this is all speculation - I still can't see why you have a problem with the basic meaning of the actual words you've highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

> was as good as I'd played

means it equalled the highest level he had played in the past.

If he had said

> was the best I'd ever played.

then it would have been a new personal best.